# How to know time difference between the local time and the android device if the auto clock is not enabled ? I need it programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I have a blockchain api with correct time, but when some android devices where the users themselves set their time (auto-clock is not enabled), I am having problem with working with this api because of the difference between these two times. Could you help me to identity this difference? System.currrentMillisSecond() method is returning the time set by the user.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have other way than syncing with 3rd-party, getting current time from e.g. own server-side or some web service and counting time basing on it. You may calculate diff between "real-time" and "on-device-time", but still user can minimalize your app and during it's work (`Service` in background?) can change again locally set time

Note that there is also `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()` which returns elapsed time since last boot. This can't be changed by user during runtime (only by restarting device), so may be helpful for counting difference

```
val synced = getTimestampFromWeb() // instead of unreliable System.currrentMillisSecond()
val elapsedWhenSynced = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()
// store these in some 
...
// use below line anytime later 
val currentTime = synced + (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - elapsedWhenSynced)
```